# Can I have a custom UI for monitoring my microservices registered to Consul?

Tags: microservices, consul, health-monitoring

I'm new to using Consul as a service discovery for the SOA. Please clarify whether I can enhance the monitoring web UI that Consul has inbuild to support my needs? Like I wish to monitor the Microservice health (CPU usage, Latency, and Disk space).  TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through consul builtin UI there is no feature of getting docker metric like cpu, memory .

Instead you can use tools like

https://github.com/google/cadvisor

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you have used consul can you suggest me the monitoring stack?